# Convert Array of objects to Hash with a field as the key

Tags: ruby, type-conversion

I have an Array of objects:

```
[
  #<User id: 1, name: "Kostas">,
  #<User id: 2, name: "Moufa">,
  ...
]
```

And I want to convert this into an Hash with the `id` as the keys and the objects as the values. Right now I do it like so but I *know* there is a better way:

```
users = User.all.reduce({}) do |hash, user|
  hash[user.id] = user
  hash
end
```

The expected output:

```
{
  1 => #<User id: 1, name: "Kostas">,
  2 => #<User id: 2, name: "Moufa">,
  ...
}
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I was looking at [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and it was almost what I'm looking for. I just thought there is a version of it the instead of building arrays for values, it is more agressive and keeps only one value.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
users_by_id = User.all.map { |user| [user.id, user] }.to_h
```

If you are using Rails, ActiveSupport provides [Enumerable#index_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by):

```
users_by_id = User.all.index_by(&:id)
```

Comment: I personally prefer the `mash` way instead of the `Hash[...]` one. It read cleaner, more ruby-like.

Comment: I believe your Ruby >= 2.1 needs a slight correction, you want .to_h not .to_a e.g. `users = User.all.map { |u| [u.id, u] }.to_h`

Answer (score 7):

You'll get a slightly better code by using `each_with_object` instead of `reduce`.

```
users = User.all.each_with_object({}) do |user, hash|
  hash[user.id] = user
end
```

Comment: Are we going to go the inject/each_with_object/Hash/mash path again? :-) http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/666

Comment: @tokland:  Yes, that was the first thought in my head when I saw your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do (using the Ruby 3 syntax of `_1`)

```
users_by_id = User.all.to_h { [_1.id, _1] }
```